# Sous vide power issue. Food safety

Tags: food-safety, beef, sous-vide

first I read the post that is similar but doesn’t answer my question.

Last night my power won’t out for a few hours.

I was cooking London broil for about 4-5 hours @125.  Around 2am the power went out. I woke up at 4 and noticed the power was out. I then checked the water bath with one of my instant read thermometers, turned out the water was about 118-121. I then took it out immediately and put it in the refrigerator since I didn’t know when the power would come back on.  This morning I out it back in the bath @125 again to finish it for this evening.

Questions are.  Since it really only takes about 2 hours to cook normally, Can I assume it was already cooked to rare, when I put it in the fridge?

Can I also assume it sitting in the water bath for approximately 2 hours at about 118-121 then the meat is fine?

Last me putting it back in the water bath this morning will everything turn out the same as if I hadn’t lost power and it would have been a 18 hour cook? Vs the 5 hours of cook, 2 hours at 120, 4 hours of fridge and now about 7 hours @125?

Comment: Can you include a link to the similar post you read? (Just so people don't refer you again to something you already tried!)

Answer (score 3):

7 hours at 125°F seems like a bad idea, no matter what happened before.

> If the food is not being pasteurized (as is the case with fish and rare meat), it is important that the food come up to temperature and be served within four hours. 
>    ... which is why cooking times **over four hours** are not shown for temperatures **below 131°F** (55°C). [emphasis added] http://www.douglasbaldwin.com/sous-vide.html#Cooking

Comment: Douglas Baldwin's guide should be mandatory reading before attempting sous vide.  It's a great resource!